# Projecting aggregated data to flat one

Tags: c#, linq, join, flatten

How can I get from this:

```
var props = new List<RoomProperties>();
props.Add(new RoomProperties(new[] {3, 4, 5}, new string[] {"AC", "WC"}));
props.Add(new RoomProperties(new[] {2}, new string[] {"AC", "TV"}));
props.Add(new RoomProperties(new[] {3}, new string[] {"Music", "Phone"}));
```

To this:

```
Key = 2, Values = ("AC", "TV") 
Key = 3, Values = ("AC", "WC","Music", "Phone" )
Key = 4, Values = ("AC", "WC") 
Key = 5, Values = ("AC", "WC")
```

With `props.props.SelectMany()` I can get keys to flatten, but values are not associated with it. If you have a good idea how do do this in elegant way I would appreciate that.
Basically I want room properties concatenated per ID and IDs are uniquely represented with that data.

```
private class RoomProperties
{
    public readonly int[] RoomIds;
    public string[] Properties { get; private set; }

    public RoomProperties(int[] roomIds, string[] properties)
    {
        RoomIds = roomIds;
        Properties = properties;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Show your `RoomProperties` class.

Comment: Its completely unclear how `RoomProperties` looks like. Its unclear where `Music` and `Phone` gone from your results. Its unclear what is your expected result

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten sequence to anonymous objects with room id and room properties. Then group these object by room id, and select all properties from group (I also added Distinct to avoid duplicated values for room):

```
props.SelectMany(p => p.RoomIds.Select(id => new { id, p.Properties }))
     .GroupBy(x => x.id)
     .Select(g => new { 
         g.Key, 
         Values = g.SelectMany(x => x.Properties).Distinct() 
     });
```

Comment: That was quick:) nice. I did'nt come up to this that you could simply use anonymous in SelectMany. Thanks

Comment: really a great example about the power of LINQ!